Rate of convergence in probability
I am reading the paper
In this paper, they proved theorem 7 which stated in the following way

Theorem 7: Let $p, q, X, Y$ be defined as in Problem 1, and assume $0 \leq k(x, y) \leq K$. Then:
$$
\Pr_{X, Y} \left\{ 
\big| \text{MMD}_b[\mathcal{F}, X, Y] - \text{MMD}[\mathcal{F}, p, q] \big| > 2 \left( \left( \frac{K}{m} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} + \left( \frac{K}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right) + \varepsilon
\right\}
\leq 
2 \exp\left(-\frac{\varepsilon^2 mn}{2K(m+n)}\right),
$$
where $Pr_{X, Y}$ denotes the probability over the $m$ - sample $X$ and $n$ -sample $Y$.

Before this theorem, the author stated that the empirical MMD converges in probability at a rate of $O((m+n)^{-\frac{1}{2}})$ to its population value. I do not understand how they concluded this rate of convergence. Could you please remind me of the definition of convergence in probability with a rate and explain how it connects to Theorem 7?

Recall that we usually say for a (real) deterministic sequence $(u_n)_{n\ge 1}$ that it converges to a limit $u$ with a rate of convergence $(r_n)_{n\ge 1}$ whenever
$$|u_n-u| = O(r_n), \tag1$$
where $r_n$ is another deterministic sequence of real numbers converging to $0$  (typically something like $n^{-\alpha}$) and $O$ is the big O notation.
By analogy with $(1)$, given (real) random variables $X,X_1,X_2\ldots$ defined on the same probability space, we can say that the sequence $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $X$ with rate $(r_n)_{n\ge 1}$ whenever
$$|X_n - X| = O_p(r_n)\tag2 $$
where, again, $r_n$ is a deterministic sequence of real numbers converging to $0$  and $O_p$ denotes a big O in probability.
Now in the context of your Theorem 7, we have $X_n \equiv \text{MMD}_b[\mathcal{F}, X, Y]$, $X\equiv \text{MMD}[\mathcal{F}, X, Y]$ and $r_n\equiv(m+n)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. It is straightforward to check that $|X_n - X|/r_n $ is indeed stochastically bounded, and so the claim of the authors is justified.
